# How do I collect HTML form data when hosting and store it on my MongoDB database?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express, nodemailer

I am trying to setup a small application to collect form data from users and store it on MongoDB database. I was able to do this on my local server by setting the HTML action attribute to point to my localhost route used for setting up the Express post method which is http://localhost:4000/login. I also connected to the MongoDB database using mongodb://localhost:27017/db and everything works fine. My question is how do I make this work on a hosting platform like Netlify which I am currently using?
Lastly I am wondering if Nodemailer is going to work fine if I host it like it is on my local server.

My code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<form action="http://localhost:4000/login" method="post">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Email address or phone number" name="email"/>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
</form>
```

Node.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport')
const Login = require('./models/schema')
const app = express()   
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body
    const response = await Login.create(data)

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
            pass: 'mypassword'
        }
    }))

    const message = {
        from: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        to: 'user@gmail.com',
        subject: 'New Sign In',
        text: `A new user has signed in...`
    }

    transporter.sendMail(message, (err, info) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        }
        console.log('Email sent: ', info.response)
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: Use relative path and it will work everywhere. `<form action="/login"`

Comment: What about the MongoDB route? Will it work too?

Comment: If the mongo runs on the same server and is accessible on localhost then yes. But i don't think netlify host a mongo for you, or does it? Anyway, mongodb must be accessible from the server the express app runs on.

Comment: I used the relative path /login in the HTML action attribute but when I hosted it on netlify and submit a form, it says the page which the form is pointing to is not found. What can I do? Or do you have a better hosting service that you can recommend?

Comment: It's not about hosting service. It's about figuring out where each part(frontend, backend, database) of your app runs and pointing them one to another. So if express app(backend) runs on different server then your frontend then you need to use absolute path(including hostname, etc) in the action attribute. This means the express app must run on publicly accessible server. The same goes for the mongodb, it must be accessible from the server the express app runs on and you need to use full url including hostname, port and dbname.